Installing hardie siding over stucco
Can I use laticrete 254 thinset to adhere planks instead of strips and nails or tapcons?

The James Hardie installation manual recommends nails or screws. (see pages 2 and 3)
There is no mention of use of thinset or any mastic. Only mechanical means.
